# Javascript tutorial, 'childNodes' solution doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Am doing a (highly recommended) Javascript tutorial (http://www.newthinktank.com/2015/09/learn-javascript-one-video/) and one of the solutions doesn't work. I'm trying to change the background colour of the first paragraph, I don't get any errors and 'developer tools' shows me that the 'style' just doesn't updated. I even copied the code from the cheat-sheet and it still doesn't work. Not sure it's a version problem or just a genuine mistake (it's been viewed over 1,000,000 times so I'm sure someone would have picked up on it by now). Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="sampDiv">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <em>consectetur adipiscing</em> elit. Integer feugiat in tortor at scelerisque. Aenean nulla dui, auctor sit amet dignissim et, ultrices non odio. Pellentesque luctus eu ligula id feugiat. Mauris tempus mollis est, eget elementum massa luctus eu.</p>
      <p> Sed ac ipsum libero. <b>Donec et leo</b> sit amet ante posuere pretium at eu massa. Donec tincidunt <em>elementum risus</em>, nec scelerisque massa luctus vitae. Praesent blandit tincidunt orci, <b>at commodo eros</b> interdum eu.</p>
    </div>
  <script>
    // first paragraph
    var sampDiv = document.getElementById('sampDiv');
    sampDiv.childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know there are many ways to achieve this, such as:

```
var pElements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
pElements[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";
```

...but I'm interested to know what is wrong. To clarify, this is the code that isn't working:

```
var sampDiv = document.getElementById('sampDiv');
sampDiv.childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";
```

I'm running Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the first child node is a Text node (containing the whitespace after `<div id="sampDiv">` and before `<p>`), not an element:

```js
var sampDiv = document.getElementById('sampDiv');
console.log(sampDiv.childNodes[0].nodeName);
```

```html
<div id="sampDiv">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <em>consectetur adipiscing</em> elit. Integer feugiat in tortor at scelerisque. Aenean nulla dui, auctor sit amet dignissim et, ultrices non odio. Pellentesque luctus eu ligula id feugiat. Mauris tempus mollis est, eget elementum massa luctus eu.</p>
  <p>Sed ac ipsum libero. <b>Donec et leo</b> sit amet ante posuere pretium at eu massa. Donec tincidunt <em>elementum risus</em>, nec scelerisque massa luctus vitae. Praesent blandit tincidunt orci, <b>at commodo eros</b> interdum eu.</p>
</div>
```

The author should have used [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), which only contains elements, instead of `childNodes`, which includes all types of nodes:

```js
var sampDiv = document.getElementById('sampDiv');
sampDiv.children[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";
```

```html
<div id="sampDiv">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <em>consectetur adipiscing</em> elit. Integer feugiat in tortor at scelerisque. Aenean nulla dui, auctor sit amet dignissim et, ultrices non odio. Pellentesque luctus eu ligula id feugiat. Mauris tempus mollis est, eget elementum massa luctus eu.</p>
  <p>Sed ac ipsum libero. <b>Donec et leo</b> sit amet ante posuere pretium at eu massa. Donec tincidunt <em>elementum risus</em>, nec scelerisque massa luctus vitae. Praesent blandit tincidunt orci, <b>at commodo eros</b> interdum eu.</p>
</div>
```

Although one could argue that [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) would be better than `children[0]`.

It may be that the author didn't have that whitespace and you introduced it with formatting, or the author normally runs his/her HTML through a compressor which would probably have removed it, etc., because the code works if that whitespace isn't there:

```js
var sampDiv = document.getElementById('sampDiv');
sampDiv.childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";
```

```html
<div id="sampDiv"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <em>consectetur adipiscing</em> elit. Integer feugiat in tortor at scelerisque. Aenean nulla dui, auctor sit amet dignissim et, ultrices non odio. Pellentesque luctus eu ligula id feugiat. Mauris tempus mollis est, eget elementum massa luctus eu.</p>
  <p>Sed ac ipsum libero. <b>Donec et leo</b> sit amet ante posuere pretium at eu massa. Donec tincidunt <em>elementum risus</em>, nec scelerisque massa luctus vitae. Praesent blandit tincidunt orci, <b>at commodo eros</b> interdum eu.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct on both counts. Removing the whitespace fixes it (the formatting was mine, the author had it right). With the whitespace, the 'children' solution works too. Thanks, learnt two new things!

Answer (score -1):

`sampDiv.childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = "#F0FFFF";`

not `childNodes[0]`, but `childNodes[1]`.

Comment: Why is the answer not useful? It works, I tried. But you should use `children` instead of `childNodes`

Comment: Because your post referred to the second paragraph [1] but the question did state I was trying to change the background colour of the first paragraph [0].

Comment: No, `childNodes[1]` is the first paragraph and `childNodes[3]` is the second paragraph.  `childNodes[0]` and `childNodes[2]` are just whitespaces.   [Here is the demo: ](https://codepen.io/cr7love/pen/qMVBZX?editors=1010)